# running macro twice leads to blank result and keep getting running error

Tags: vba, if-statement, ms-word, inputbox, msgbox

I am having 2 issues with my code.

First issue: I cant get it to save as the oriTitle when I am running the macro for the second time and answer with no to the question if I wanted to change the title. It will just be blank.

Second issue: I can only save it for 2 times. After that, I'll get running error. I'd like to keep going for at least 10 times.

Could someone help me with both issues? I have no clue what to do. Thanks in advance!

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
   
    Const FilePath As String = "//SRVDC\Arbeitsordner\Intern\Meetings\Entwürfe\"
    Const OrigFileName As String = "20210910_Besprechungsnotizen_00_"
    Dim MyDate As String: MyDate = Format(Date, "YYYYMMDD")
    Dim Title As String
    Dim oriTitle As String: oriTitle = "Besprechungsnotizen"
    Dim newTitle As String
    Dim currentTitle As String
    Dim User As String
    Dim newUser As String
    Dim currentUser As String
    Dim Version As Integer
    Dim newVersion As Integer
    Dim currentVersion As Integer
    

    If Split(ActiveDocument.Name, ".")(0) = OrigFileName Then
        'file has not been resaved
    Else
        'file has been saved before so extract data from filename
        Dim nameElements As Variant
        nameElements = Split(Split(ActiveDocument.Name, ".")(0), "_")
        User = nameElements(UBound(nameElements))
        Version = nameElements(UBound(nameElements) - 1)
    End If
    If User = "" Then
    User = InputBox("Wer erstellt? (Name in Firmenkurzform)")
    newTitle = MsgBox("Anderer Titel?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2, "Titel")
        If newTitle = vbYes Then
            Title = InputBox("Wie soll der Titel sein?")
        Else
            Title = oriTitle
        End If
    Version = "0"
Else
    currentUser = InputBox("Wer bearbeitet? (Name in Firmenkurzform)")
        If currentUser = User Then
        
        Else
            User = User & "_" & currentUser
        End If
    newTitle = MsgBox("Neuer Titel?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2, "Titel")
        If newTitle = vbYes Then
            Title = InputBox("Wie soll der neue Titel sein?")
    Else
    End If
        Version = MsgBox("Neue Version?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2, "Version")
        If Version = vbYes Then
            newVersion = currentVersion + 1
            Version = newVersion
        Else
            Version = currentVersion
        End If
    End If
    
    ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 FilePath & MyDate & "_" & Title & "_i_0" & Version & "_" & User

End Sub
```

Comment: `User = User & "_" & currentUser` You use this to add the names together, but that would ruin the code earlier `Version = nameElements(UBound(nameElements) - 1)` because the second last element in the name is not a number but a second name. That should give a type mismatch error, trying to assign an integer to a string

Comment: `If User = "" Then` is the only section where `Title` gains a value. which means if you go to the `Else` section, `Title` is blank, if the user selects NO, `currentTitle` is also assigned blank. and the final document name has a blank title.

Comment: I should also mention, the document name is created using `Title`. Ignoring whatever the user entered as the `currentTitle`

Comment: I tried saving every Title as currentTitle so if a new Title has not been given, that the Title should be the last currentTitle. but I am still having the same issue that after pressing no for 2 times, I'll get a blank title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to another post and the main help of Timothy, I was able to finish my code. here's what I got in case somebody in the future is trying something similar.
And I even addded the option to save as PDF and decide if this is supposed to be a new version or not.
Here saving as word:

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

Const FilePath As String = "//SRVDC\Arbeitsordner\Intern\Meetings\Entwürfe\"
Const OrigFileName As String = "20210910_Besprechungsnotizen_00_"
Dim Title As String: Title = "Besprechungsnotizen"
Dim newTitle As String
Dim MyDate As String: MyDate = Format(Date, "YYYYMMDD")
Dim User As String
Dim Version As String

If Split(ActiveDocument.Name, ".")(0) = OrigFileName Then
    'file has not been resaved
Else
    'file has been saved before so extract data from filename
    Dim nameElements As Variant
    nameElements = Split(Split(ActiveDocument.Name, ".")(0), "_")
    User = nameElements(UBound(nameElements))
    Version = nameElements(UBound(nameElements) - 1)
    Title = nameElements(UBound(nameElements) - 3)
End If
If User = "" Then
    User = InputBox("Wer erstellt? (Name in Firmenkurzform)")
    newTitle = MsgBox("Anderer Titel?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2, "Titel")
        If newTitle = vbYes Then
            Title = InputBox("Wie soll der Titel sein?")
        Else
        End If
    Version = "0"
Else
    Dim currentUser As String
    currentUser = InputBox("Wer bearbeitet? (Name in Firmenkurzform)")
    If currentUser = User Then
    Else
        User = User & currentUser
    End If
    Version = Format$(Version + 1, "0")
    
End If

ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 FilePath & MyDate & "_" & Title & "_i_0" & Version & "_" & User
End Sub
```

Here the PDF part

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Const FilePath As String = "//SRVDC\Arbeitsordner\Intern\Meetings\Finale Versionen\"
Const OrigFileName As String = "20210910_Besprechungsnotizen_00_"
Dim Title As String: Title = "Besprechungsnotizen"
Dim newTitle As String
Dim MyDate As String: MyDate = Format(Date, "YYYYMMDD")
Dim User As String
Dim Version As String

If Split(ActiveDocument.Name, ".")(0) = OrigFileName Then
    'file has not been resaved
Else
    'file has been saved before so extract data from filename
    Dim nameElements As Variant
    nameElements = Split(Split(ActiveDocument.Name, ".")(0), "_")
    User = nameElements(UBound(nameElements))
    Version = nameElements(UBound(nameElements) - 1)
    Title = nameElements(UBound(nameElements) - 3)
End If
If User = "" Then
    User = InputBox("Wer erstellt? (Name in Firmenkurzform)")
    newTitle = MsgBox("Anderer Titel?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2, "Titel")
        If newTitle = vbYes Then
            Title = InputBox("Wie soll der Titel sein?")
        Else
        End If
    Version = "0"
Else
    newVersion = MsgBox("Neue Version?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2, "Neue Version")
        If newVersion = vbYes Then
        Dim currentUser As String
        currentUser = InputBox("Wer bearbeitet? (Name in Firmenkurzform)")
            If currentUser = User Then
            Else
                User = User & currentUser
            End If
        Version = Format$(Version + 1)
        Else
        Version = Format$(Version)
        End If
End If


ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:=FilePath & _
                                MyDate & "_" & Title & "_i_0" & Version & "_" & User & ".pdf", _
                                ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, _
                                OpenAfterExport:=False, _
                                OptimizeFor:=wdExportOptimizeForPrint, _
                                Range:=wdExportAllDocument, _
                                IncludeDocProps:=True, _
                                CreateBookmarks:=wdExportCreateWordBookmarks, _
                                BitmapMissingFonts:=True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are simply not thinking anything through. You have also simply used the code given to you in a previous answer without first ensuring that you understand it.

NEVER use code you get from the internet without first working through it line by line and ensuring that you fully understand what each part of the code does. You can use the tools in the Visual Basic Editor to help with this. Place your cursor in a term you don't understand and press <kbd>F2</kbd> to display the Object Browser, or <kbd>F1</kbd> to access the online help.

I have added comments to the code to indicate your mistakes.

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
   
    Const FilePath As String = "//SRVDC\Arbeitsordner\Intern\Meetings\Entwürfe\"
    Const OrigFileName As String = "20210910_Besprechungsnotizen_00_"
    Dim MyDate As String: MyDate = Format(Date, "YYYYMMDD")
    Dim Title As String
    Dim oriTitle As String: oriTitle = "Besprechungsnotizen"
    Dim newTitle As String
    Dim currentTitle As String
    Dim User As String
    Dim newUser As String
    Dim currentUser As String
    Dim Version As Integer
    Dim newVersion As Integer
    Dim currentVersion As Integer
    

    If Split(ActiveDocument.Name, ".")(0) = OrigFileName Then
        'file has not been resaved
    Else
        'file has been saved before so extract data from filename
        Dim nameElements As Variant
        nameElements = Split(Split(ActiveDocument.Name, ".")(0), "_")
        User = nameElements(UBound(nameElements))
        Version = nameElements(UBound(nameElements) - 1)
    End If
    If User = "" Then
        User = InputBox("Wer erstellt? (Name in Firmenkurzform)")
        'why are you using Title here when it is the variable used to save the document?
        'you should use newTitle for the MsgBox return value
        Title = MsgBox("Anderer Titel?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2, "Titel")
        If Title = vbYes Then
            'you should be using the Titlke variable here, not newTitle
            newTitle = InputBox("Wie soll der Titel sein?")
            'corect the prvious two lines and these next two can be deleted
            Title = newTitle
            'this sets newTitle to a blank string as you haven't assigned a value to currentTitle yet
            newTitle = currentTitle
        Else
            Title = oriTitle
            'this sets oriTitle to a blank string as you haven't assigned a value to currentTitle yet
            oriTitle = currentTitle
        End If
        Version = "0"
    Else
        currentUser = InputBox("Wer bearbeitet? (Name in Firmenkurzform)")
        If currentUser = User Then
            
        Else
            'if you use an underscore to separate the user names you will not be able to extract
            'the version number
            'you need to use a different character to separate the names and then use the Split
            'function to return those names as an array
            User = User & "_" & currentUser
        End If
        'see comments above
        Title = MsgBox("Neuer Titel?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2, "Titel")
        If Title = vbYes Then
            newTitle = InputBox("Wie soll der neue Titel sein?")
            Title = newTitle
            newTitle = currentTitle
        Else
            Title = currentTitle
        End If
        'comments above also apply here. You should have used the newVersion variable for the MsgBox
        Version = MsgBox("Neue Version?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2, "Version")
        If Version = vbYes Then
            newVersion = currentVersion + 1
            Version = newVersion
        Else
            'you haven't assigned a value to currentVersion yet so it will set Version to zero
            Version = currentVersion
        End If
    End If
    
    ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 FilePath & MyDate & "_" & Title & "_i_0" & Version & "_" & User

End Sub
```

Comment: I am trying to understand it but I really cant get it. I mean I've fixed your comments regarding the title, but the issue remains. word is still giving me a blank output since the content from oriTitle or as a matter of fact the previous title at all isnt being saved as a variable. I guess thats why it isnt doing what I want it to do.

Comment: @Jens1411 - My comments weren't limited to just the title. As Toddleson also pointed out, the way you delimit the multiple user names also breaks the code.

Comment: I understand but I cant solve all problems at once. And your F1 and F2 advice isnt working for me. I might just be too stupid for that. I am trying to use the activedocuments' name and only the part that is considered to be the title. So i tried using ActiveDocument.name but it will then give me the entire file name and not just the title part of it. and regarding the wanting to save multiple times and the "_" is something I cant deal with at the same time.. been working on this issue for hours and just trying to fix the title for god's sake. I've never worked with VBA before.

Comment: @Jens1411 - then go back to the code that you were given before and just change the part that deals with the title. Then *think carefully* about how you handle the multiple user names. You've dug yourself into hole by attempting to make multiple changes to code you don't understand. Take it one step at a time.

Comment: the code before works perfectly for what I asked for. but I dont understand the code. so trying to make it work is exactly the difficulty. on the other hand, not having it is even harder cause on the internet I cant find solutions to exactly what I am trying to do and those F1 + F2 dont explain how to use it to me. Like if I search for filename, what is it gonna tell me? nothing that helps. but I'll go back to your previous code and hope I can somehow make this work cause your code seems solid